# Preserving the Java-type of an object when passing it from Java to Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I wonder if it possible to **not** have jython automagicaly transform java objects to python types when you put them in a Java ArrayList.

Example copied from a jython-console:

```
>>> b = java.lang.Boolean("True");
>>> type(b)
<type 'javainstance'>
>>> isinstance(b, java.lang.Boolean);
1
```

So far, everything is fine but if I put the object in an ArrayList

```
>>> l = java.util.ArrayList();
>>> l.add(b)
1
>>> type(l.get(0))
<type 'int'>
```

the object is transformed into a python-like boolean (i.e. an int) and...

```
>>> isinstance(l.get(0), java.lang.Boolean)
0
```

which means that I can no longer see that this was once a java.lang.Boolean.

**Clarification**

I guess what really want to achieve is to get rid of the implicit conversion from Java-types to Python-types when passing objects from Java to Python. I will give another example for clarification.

A Python module:

```
import java

import IPythonModule

class PythonModule(IPythonModule):

    def method(self, data):
        print type(data);
```

And a Java-Class that uses this module:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.python.core.PyList;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.*;

public class Test1 {

    IPythonModule m;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        JythonFactory jf = JythonFactory.getInstance();
        m = (IPythonModule) jf.getJythonObject(
                "IPythonModule",
        "/Users/sg/workspace/JythonTests/src/PythonModule.py");
    }

    @Test
    public void testFirst() {
        m.method(new Boolean("true"));
    }   
}
```

Here I will see the output 'bool' because of the implicit conversion, but what I would really like is to see 'javainstance' or 'java.lang.Boolean'. If you want to run this code you will also need the JythonFactory-class that can be found [here](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonMonthly/Articles/September2006/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using an old version of Jython.  In current Jython versions, the Python `bool` type corresponds to a Java `Boolean`.

Jython is not transforming the Java type to a Python type on the way into the `ArrayList` - on the contrary, it will transform a primitive Python type to a primitive or wrapper Java type when passing it to a Java method, and a Java type to a Python type on the way out.

You can observe this by printing the contents of the array.  Note that the Python `bool` is capitalized (`True`); the Java `Boolean` is not.

```
>>> from java.lang import Boolean
>>> b = Boolean('True')
>>> b      
true
>>> from java.util import ArrayList
>>> l = ArrayList()
>>> l.add(b)
True
>>> l
[true]
>>> l.add(True)
True
>>> l
[true, true]
>>> list(l) 
[True, True]
```

If this still doesn't do what you want, consider writing a small Java helper function that examines the array for you without conversion.  It's arguably a bug that Jython doesn't automatically convert the `Boolean` you constructed into a Python `bool`, and in this case it gives you no advantage over using `Boolean.TRUE` or the Python `True`.

Comment: Yes I am using the latest stable version, 2.2.1 which does not have support for the python bool type... Downloading 2.5b right now...

Comment: >>> b = java.lang.Boolean("true");
>>> l = java.util.ArrayList();
>>> l.add(b)
True
>>> type(l.get(0))
<type 'bool'>
>>> isinstance(l.get(0), java.lang.Boolean)
False

As far as I can see, conversion still takes place, and it is this conversion that I don't want.

Comment: There's actually 2 potential conversions happening here, one going into the array and one coming out.  When it's in the ArrayList, you've got a java.lang.Boolean, which you can see because it prints with a lowercase 't'.

Comment: Since you can rely on this conversion on the way out, you can use isinstance(l.get(0), bool) or isinstance(l[0], bool).

Comment: For sure! : ) The "updating to the latest version"-trick works fine with the bool-types. Next problem is seperate the Java-Floats from the Java-Doubles, which both of course get's converted to pythons 'float'-type... Anyway, thanks for the help this far!